# Repairing Garage Door Control Board

Tags: diodes, ac, dc

**Update summary:**

I recapped the whole board :D - It works perfectly!
Re the main/bigger cap, my local electrics shop didn't have a 330uF 35V so I went for a 470uF 35V instead.

Just for my own learning, was the problem was that the main cap C25 wasn't able to hold charge properly - meaning that the output DC voltage wasn't stable/smooth ? I guess this would explain the "50hz" clicking of the relay (that now only clicks once when the board is powered up)

---

I'm after some help to repair the control board on my (ancient) garage door opener.  Symptoms are the system not working, but a relay rapidly firing when power supplied to the board.

I've taken some readings across the rectifier bridge, and (assuming I'm measuring at the correct points) I'm not seeing pure DC like I would expect.

Readings one side of the voltage regulator are also okay - but not the other.

I guess this indicates that one or more diodes on the rectifier bridge have failed. Do these look like 5 W 22 V Zener diodes? Any strategy on which ones to replace? Or do I just try replacing one at a time.

[image: Garage Door Opener Board]

**Update #1:** Have added photo of front and back of board as requested:

[image: FrontAndBackOfBoard]

**Update #2:** Resistance readings across the rectifier diodes (with one leg lifted from the board in each case):

D4: 47 kΩ (and 0 in reverse)
D5: 55 kΩ (and 0 in reverse)
D6: 48 kΩ (and 0 in reverse)
D7: 73 kΩ (and 0 in reverse)

**Update #3:** **It works again!** Here's how things look after recapping. Thank you @Gil - this is a 30+ year old board (which I can't source anymore), and means I don't have to replace the whole garage door unit :D

[image: ItWorks]

**Update #4:** For interest, side-by-side comparison of the old (blu-tacked and floating!) cap vs the new. Slight bulge (I guess? - to my untrained eye) compared to the new. The replacement 470 uF also quite a bit taller than the original 330 uF old. Also found a date stamp for the original device, which was Aug 1996, so 27 years old!

[image]

Comment: The "not pure DC" tells nothing about how you determined that, nor what it exactly means. And there's no schematic here, either, and you don't show both sides of the board (nor side profile so the electrolytic can be better evaluated visually.) You may need to write more, perhaps work out for us the schematic section under concern, and provide some more photos.

Comment: @periblepsis: I don't have a schematic I'm afraid, but I can certainly try to upload some better photos.  Re the "not pure DC" on the voltage regulator: With my multimeter I get 5V DC (and 0V AC) at the points indicated, but at the "not pure DC": 14.5V DC and 8.2V AC.  It seems that AC is making it through to the circuitry where only DC should be expected ?

Comment: Those diodes probably aren't zeners, but just plan old Si rectifier diodes.  If one is blown, then that may cause excessive ripple on the DC which may explain the relay chatter.  You could ohm out each diode, but probably need to lift one leg off the board so that you don't have any sneak/parallel paths (like the transformer secondary) that would corrupt your measurement.

Comment: Thank you for the hints @SteveSh.  I will upload some higher res versions of the board (as noted by @periblepsis) and also take some measurements of the Si Rectifier Diodes.  Thanks again :)

Comment: @periblepsis Have edited the original post to include front and back images of the full board.

Comment: @SteveSh: Have carefully lifted a leg on each diode and have updated the original post with some readings.

Comment: Those numbers sound reasonable for rectifier diodes, which tend to be leakier and so have lower reverse resistance than small signal diodes.  Though it's been a long since I had to actually measure such parameters.

Comment: Hmmm - I guess the fault must be somewhere else then.

Comment: That appears to be a typical filter capacitor failure. Carefully replace the caps and try again. Also explain how you are measuring AC and DC with what instrument.

Comment: @Gil Would that be Cap C25 ?  And re the measurements - just a standard Digital Multimeter (dt9205a), in AC voltage mode vs DC.

Comment: Yes they are both puffing up which is not good. The silicone rectifiers appear to be OK.

Comment: Thanks @Gil - appreciate the help.  Might take a day or two to get replacement Caps, will check in again once that's done :)

Comment: If that solves it let me know I will put it in answer format and repost it.

Comment: @Gil I don't think anyone's ever made a rectifier out of silicon**e** ... ;)

Comment: @Gil It works perfectly!  I recapped the whole board :D. (I know there are only two caps.). Re the main/bigger cap, my local electrics shop didn't have a 330uF 35V so I went for a 470uF 35V instead.  Pretty sure this is kosha because it's a smoothing cap.

Comment: Just for my own learning, was the problem was that the main cap C25 wasn't able to hold charge properly - meaning that the output DC voltage wasn't stable/smooth ?  I guess this would explain the "50hz" clicking of the relay (that now only clicks once when the board is powered up)

Comment: Just to close the loop re the "not pure DC" on the original photo: Just under the text "~22V", now I am getting a reading of 0V AC at the points indicated (and a DC reading of 30V).  Prior to the cap replacement, I was getting some AC values on my multimeter here.

Comment: @PatrickRynhart That's why I wanted a side profile picture -- to see the caps better. Glad all that worked !

Comment: @periblepsis: Ah right!  Side profile for comparison of old vs new filter caps uploaded under "Update 4".  Also found a date stamp on the device, August 1996!  So 27 years old :)

Comment: Did you glue the black capacitor in place to make it float in mid-air for the photo?

Comment: @winny: Not glue - Just Blu Tack (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu_Tack) :)

Comment: @PatrickRynhart Ah! Sweet childhood memories.

Comment: @PatrickRynhart The final update should be an *answer* to your own question - not an edit to the question. Yes, you can (and should - if you can!) answer your own questions.

Comment: Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica: Thanks for that but it was @Gil who determined the root cause :)  I'm really appreciative to the community who have helped me to crowd source a solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be a typical filter capacitor failure. Carefully replace the caps C25 and C26 and try again. The reason is they are both puffing up which is a sign of impending failure if not already failed. This is not good. The rectifiers appear to be OK